# Creating a Cost Profile

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me with this little problem.  I will try and explain as bets i can!!
We have a P6 schedule exported into Excel (Dont ask why we dont just do this in P6) and a some estimates.  We have a start and finish date for each activity from the schedule dump and the cost of each activity from the estimte.  What we would like to be able to do is be able to spread these costs in a cost loaded curve.  Simple enough if every activity will have the same cost profile.  But they dont and here is the tricky bit.  We would like to be able to select the profile 6 in all and then excel would do its magic and proportion the cost between the 2 dates according to the cost profile selected...  Simples, I hope!!

```
Curve Profiles                                          
1   10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 100%
2   1%  2%  3%  7%  13% 17% 20% 19% 13% 5%  100%
3   5%  13% 19% 20% 17% 13% 7%  3%  2%  1%  100%
4   3%  7%  11% 14% 15% 15% 14% 11% 7%  3%  100%
5   100%    0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  100%
6   0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  100%    100%
```

P6 is Primavera is a planning tool. We are going to use polynomial formula to determine what the split is along the line for the total value. =3.10862446895044E-15*C16^6 + 0.0000128205126657122*C16^5 - 0.000384615378834496*C16^4 + 0.00211538450821536*C16^3 + 0.0173076931969263*C16^2 - 0.0324778592548682*C16 + 0.0136363733254257 We are struggling to work out how to get excel to determine the date set automatically. Below is a cut of the data.

```
Activity ID Activity Name   Duration    Start   Finish  Total Month Total Float Budgeted Total Cost
A1740   Major Permissions - Project Management  734 01-Apr-17   22-Feb-19   23  1939    £6,748,243
A1630   MPP2 - Main Site DCO Contracts  742 01-Apr-17   06-Mar-19   24  1931    £6,027,265
A1650   MPP3 - SP&C Contracts   553 01-Apr-17   08-Jun-18   15  2120    £299,795
A1660   MPP4 - Highways Contracts   443 01-Apr-17   29-Dec-17   9   2230    £881,005
A1670   MPP5 - Worker's Accomodation Contracts  445 01-Apr-17   03-Jan-18   10  2228    £920,193
A1690   MPP6 - Logistics, Park & Ride Contracts 746 01-Apr-17   12-Mar-19   24  1927    £581,667
A1720   MPP7 - Marine Licences Contracts    709 01-Apr-17   18-Jan-19   22  1964    £1,879,577
A1730   MPP8 - Environmental Permits Contracts  546 01-Apr-17   30-May-18   14  2127    £1,291,958
```

Comment: Please, clearify your problem, and post which you tried

Comment: The problem is i need to be able to get the sheet to auto update the activity lines based on the curve they chose to use..

Comment: Bit more data for you.  We are getting there slowly.

Answer (score 0):

We did it!! Dont ask me how but someone with a much bigger brain then me worked out the formula. If anyone wants it just ask and i can send it over without the data just the formula. Here is a taster!! 
Used for working out the time scale.

```
=IF(MONTH($D8)&YEAR($D8)=MONTH(I$2)&YEAR(I$2),(1-((DAY($D8)-1)/HLOOKUP(MONTH($D8),Monthdays,'Base Data'!$A$4,FALSE))),IF(MONTH($E8)&YEAR($E8)=MONTH(I$2)&YEAR(I$2),(DAY($E8))/HLOOKUP(MONTH($E8),Monthdays,'Base Data'!$A$4,FALSE)+H8,IF(OR(MONTH($E8)&YEAR($E8)=(MONTH(I$2)-1)&YEAR(I$2),MONTH($E8)&YEAR($E8)=12&YEAR(I$2)-1),0,IF(H8-G8>0,H8+1,H8))))
```

For the cost.

```
=IF(OR('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Linear",'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Project-S; Early",'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Project-S",'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Project-S; Late"),((VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,2,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176)^6+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,3,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176)^5+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,4,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176)^4+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,5,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176)^3+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,6,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176)^2+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,7,FALSE)*(11*'Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176))
+VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,8,FALSE)*('Time-Phase'!I176/'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176))*'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$F176,IF(AND('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Upfront Payment",'Time-Phase'!I176>0,'Time-Phase'!I176<=1),'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$F176*VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,8,FALSE),IF(AND('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176="Final Payment",'Time-Phase'!I176='Cumulative Cash Flow'!$H176),'Cumulative Cash Flow'!$F176*VLOOKUP('Cumulative Cash Flow'!$G176,Curvetype,8,FALSE),0)))
```